# Python: Access members of a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Say I have a set `myset` of custom objects that may be equal although their references are different (`a == b and a is not b`). Now if I `add(a)` to the set, Python correctly assumes that `a in myset and b in myset` even though there is only `len(myset) == 1` object in the set.

That is clear. But is it now possible to extract the value of `a` somehow out from the set, using `b` only? Suppose that the objects are mutable and I want to change them both, having forgotten the direct reference to `a`. Put differently, I am looking for the `myset[b]` operation, which would return exactly the member `a` of the set.

It seems to me that the type `set` cannot do this (faster than iterating through all its members). If so, is there at least an effective work-around?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you already have `b`, why do you need `a`, which is equal?

Comment: That is one fugly requirement...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: the element inside the set is referenced from somewhere else (from inside a deep structure) and I want to change its value. The objects are basically of 2D vector type, and they are mutable.

Comment: @emu: wait, what?  You can't mutate a dict key or a set entry; it'll (probably) change the hash and break the dict/set.  You could work with a dict in which the key is the "value" and the value is a list or set of elements which have that value, but you shouldn't go mutating anything on the "left".

Comment: @DSM: Oops, how could I not realize? Well, the question still makes sense, because I could modify an attribute that does not affect hashing or equality comparison. But for my original case it is useless, so I'll have to write it differently anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @emu: Mutable items in a set is generally a bad idea, but it could work. You could 1) retrieve the element from the set/dict 2) remove it from the set/dict 3) mutate it 4) reinsert it in the set/dict. This will work even if you change the hash and it is still O(1).

Comment: @MarkByers: you'll note I warned against *mutating* the entries, not against *mutable* entries.  ;^)

Comment: @emu ...so why isn't `b` already an alias for `a` to begin with?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In my case, they were linked from different other objects as a graph-like structure. Two points of a polygon that happen to share their location. I tried to clean it up afterwards (and keep only one of them), but that also faces the original problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that `set` supports retrieving an item in O(1) time, but you could use a `dict` instead.

```
d = {}
d[a] = a
retrieved_a = d[b]
```

Comment: In fact I tooled around with this and looked at the source a while ago, and IIRC, cpython always iterates over the smaller set when looking for intersections. So what you have works, but if `s` is longer, this will return `b`.

Comment: @senderle: I think you're right - [source for set](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c). Then my second approach fails, so I'm deleting it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have `myset` and `b`, then from that perspective, you won't have access to `a` because it's not there. If you create multiple mutable objects and add one of them to `myset` then the others are not 'known' when you're dealing with just `myset` or the object that you added.

If you want to modify `a` and `b` then you need to keep track of both objects somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
(myset - (myset - set([b]))).pop() is a
```

Comment: It works, but the set difference (namely the first one) most probably requires Python to remove all elements one by one. Because of that, it is asymptotically the same slow as iterating through the set.

Comment: @emu: maybe, although I guess there might be some optimizations for edge cases. Anyways, I'm afraid this is the only way using _only_ sets, without resorting to dicts or linear search.